# What does $E_\theta(X) : R^D \rightarrow R$ mean?

Tags: probability

I'm reading [a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.03263). In this paper,

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN37p.jpg)

I don't understand what "$E_\theta(X) : R^D \rightarrow R$" means.

I found that $R^D$ means D-dimensional vector on the web but can't still understand the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This notation just means it's a function, named $E_θ$, which takes in $D$-dimensional vectors $\vec x$ with real coordinates, which come from $\Bbb R^D$, and maps them to a scalar in $\Bbb R$. Such a function could be, say, if we let $\vec x = (x_1,\cdots,x_D)$,

$$f\Big((x_1,x_2,x_3,⋯,x_D)\Big)=x_1+x_2+x_3+⋯+x_D$$